# Fix "I know that XYZ" misconception in question?

Tags: discussion

[Quoting](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102894/can-software-licensed-under-gnu-general-public-license-v3-be-sold-by-the-origina):

> I know softwares licensed under the GNU GPL is totally free and not
> allowed for sale.

This is a common misconception, but the question takes it for given. Is it allowed to at least moderate this to "I <strike>know</strike> believe", so that people skimming the questions don't get the wrong idea? This is a fairly benign example (except that it looks like another one of the countless examples of GPL FUD) since it's so easily refuted, but it appears in all sorts of forms:

> What is `gcc` doing wrong with my code?
>
> Why didn't Bill Gates get a medal for inventing the Internet?
>
> How did Hans Reiser's murder conviction affect the ReiserFS project?

All of them are the SO equivalent of tabloid headings, but one of these contains a valid premise and can be given a reasonable reply. People browsing this forum might get the wrong idea if stuff like this is not corrected.

**Edit**: *How* would you correct this? Possibilities include at least (including original spelling):

1. "I <strike>know</strike> believe softwares licensed under the GNU GPL is totally free and not allowed for sale." The <strike>strikeout</strike> makes it clear that it's edited. Don't know whether this is something we want to include.
2. "I believe softwares licensed under the GNU GPL is totally free and not allowed for sale." Doesn't include the original text, so the author could say we're putting words in her mouth. Of course that could be refuted by looking at the revisions, but it still sounds like attributing an opinion to the original author. Also, the second part of the premise ("not allowed for sale") is still wrong, and should probably be edited as well.
3. "I <strike>know</strike> erroneously believe softwares licensed under the GNU GPL is totally free and not allowed for sale." Could be considered insulting.
4. "I erroneously believe softwares licensed under the GNU GPL is totally free and not allowed for sale."
5. "Softwares licensed under the GNU GPL is free as in freedom." True and neutral, but not the same tone as the original author.

Comment: I would be happy to see edits like this.

Comment: I didn't know Hans Reiser was convicted of murder. O.o

Comment: @Rocket, you'll want to [read up on it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Reiser#Trial_and_verdict).

Comment: @Charles: Thanks for the link.  Also, wow o.O

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add a comment that explains that this is wrong, or if answering the question definitely add a note to that effect.

If correcting the question does not make the original question completely different, by all means edit it and correct it - and explain the reasoning in your edit summary.

Answer (score 7):

In certain cases, yes, and maybe in most. But I don't think there is a catch-all option.

At times you need to consider whether or not it with alter the substance of the query: it could be that part of the OPs dilemma is *because* of their misconception, and this can be addressed in the informative answers.

It gets murky when we start looking at specific examples like the one you give, considering there would be the argument that we're not here to provide answers or education on licences per se, but there's a responsibility, one way or the other.

To address your *other* examples, though, that is easy:

> What is gcc doing wrong with my code?

- this is just a variation on a theme, and can nearly always be corrected to remove unwarranted blame, etc.

> Why didn't Bill Gates get a medal for inventing the Internet?

- this is unwelcome anywhere on the network (to my knowledge - unless we have a subjective.stackexchange now?), so don't edit, vote to close.

> How did Hans Reiser's murder conviction affect the ReiserFS project?

- as above, help get rid of it.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't come up with SO-applicable examples. They were more examples to show the different forms of the same concept.

Answer (score 5):

In general, I wouldn't edit this, but comment or answer instead. I consider it part of the comments or answer to fix the original poster's misconceptions.

Sometimes keeping the original mistake in the question and "fixing" it via a comment or an answer will be also useful to other users which hold the same misconception.

Comment: **Sometimes keeping the original mistake in the question and "fixing" it via a comment or an answer will be also useful to other users which hold the same misconception.** and less likely to lead to an edit war when someone who believes that misconception (possible the question asker) rolls the 'correction' back.